# jQuery conflict issues between jScrollPane and NivoSlider WP plugin

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, nivo-slider

I'm having a conflict issue with [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) and the NivoSlider WP plugin. Prior to installing NivoSlider, jScrollPane was working fine. After installing it I'm getting the following error:

```
$('.scrollpane').jScrollPane is not a function
```

I've tried every combination of jQuery.noConflict that I know of and that is listed in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

I've also tried all of the recommendations found here: [jScrollPane Scrollbar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773821/jscrollpane-scrollbar-problem)

That includes using the WPScrollPane plugin which does not seem to work although it does stop the error from occurring.

Here are the pastebins with the conflicting JS:

- [NivoSlider](http://pastebin.com/GenKX5fv)
- [jScrollPane](http://pastebin.com/1SCZ51JB)

Comment: It is often easier to solve the problem by replicating it in JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked down the problem causing this issue. The NivoSlider WP plugin was including an additional version of jQuery through the [wp_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) hook in Wordpress. To fix the issue I went into the plugin files and edited nivoslider4wp-show.php.

In my Wordpress install:

> {wordpress directory}/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-for-wordpress/nivoslider4wp-show.php

And on line #32 I deleted:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Issue resolved!