# extra white line under li items that have no border

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a problem with extra white lines showing up under my list items. It's not a border as I haven't set any borders, except the one under My Account, it's just to show that the white line is not a border. The one under it is -- a 4px border the same color as the background.

This problem occurred after I had resolved a conflict between my Nivo Slider and the Woocommerce plugin on my WP site. I got both of them to work together, but then this other issue with the list cropped up. Any ideas as to what caused this and how to fix it?

[image]

Here's my CSS if that helps:

```
#header #navigation ul.nav > li.current_page_item > a 
{ color: #D4145A;}
#header #navigation ul.nav > li:hover a {
border-width: 0px 0px 4px;
border-style: none none solid;
border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color rgb(212, 20, 90);
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
border-image: none;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(212, 20, 90);}
```

and the HTML for it too:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="col-full parent" role="navigation">
<ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl parent">
<li class="page_item"></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-11"></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-12"></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-13 parent"></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-15 current_page_item parent">
<a href=""></a>
<ul class="children"></ul></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Help please! I'm at my wits' end! Thanks!

Just to add:

This is how it looked before I fixed the conflict between my Nivo Slider and Woocommerce plugins:

[url=http://postimage.org/image/lx50u5qxx/]      [img]http://s10.postimage.org/lx50u5qxx/noextraline.jpg[/img][/url]

http://postimage.org/image/lx50u5qxx/

If I go back and remove the fix to the Nivo-Woocommerce js conflict, my nav goes back to its old pretty self as linked above without the white lines.

My fix to the Nivo-Woocommerce conflict was this one that I found on here:

[jQuery conflict issues between jScrollPane and NivoSlider WP plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033167/jquery-conflict-issues-between-jscrollpane-and-nivoslider-wp-plugin)

Many thanks for the answers so far. Hope somebody out there can help me out.

ADDED:

Just noticed that in the above "before" image, the down arrows are not showing, which they are supposed to, and only shows up when I do the Nivo "fix". I guess that has something to do with it too? The css for the arrows is this:

```
#header #navigation ul.nav > li.parent a::after {
font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
display: inline-block;
font-size: .857em;
margin-left: .618em;
content: ";";
color: #dedede;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Use your developer tools (Chrome/Safari) or  Firebug (Firefox), hilight the element, figure out where the extra space is coming from, and fix it. This is the answer to pretty much *every single question* involving tracking down where some CSS is being introduced.

Comment: Can you post all your code?

Comment: I did use them (Chrome/Firefox) and highlighted the element as you said and tried all sorts of combinations of fixes from margins to borders to padding and set everything to 0. I've been working on this combo of fixes for over a day and still no relief whatsoever!

Comment: Any chance for a link to your site? Or at least can you create a test on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Hi Nikola, here it is: http://632expertise.com/mystile/

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a border, it is probably a margin. Try giving the `<li>`

```
margin:0;
```

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely margins, i made one of these once and i think that's automatic unless you change it

Comment: It's not. I've tried the margin:0; fix, it doesn't work. As you can see from the pic, the white line is INSIDE the 4px red border that I placed to highlight the white line in the box, and margins go OUTSIDE the border, right? so adding a margin just adds another level of white space after the red border.

Comment: the red border that I'm talking about is the bottom red border that I've added to the "My Account" box.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
border : 0;
outline : 0;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
```

That should do it...

Comment: But what if she still wants padding?

Comment: From looking at the code, it seems there is no explicit padding.

Comment: this is how the nav looked before I fixed the Nivo slider-Woocommerce conflict I was talking about: [url=http://postimage.org/image/lx50u5qxx/][img]http://s10.postimage.org/lx50u5qxx/noextraline.jpg[/img][/url] http://postimage.org/image/lx50u5qxx/

Comment: Ok, then keep the padding, but set all others as 0.

Comment: I did. Nothing changed. Thanks though.